# Реализация авторегрессионного метода Прони в Python, пакет statsmodels

Tags: python

Существует метод представления сигнала в виде суммы затухающих (модулированных синусоидой) экспонент - метод Прони. Существуют его реализации, основанные на подгонке суммой экспонент методом наименьших квадратов, либо определением определения параметров модели авторегрессии-скользящего среднего. Существуют ли готовая реализация в библиотеке на Python или методе в statsmodels процедуры разложения сигнала методом Прони?

Comment: https://github.com/awesomebytes/parametric_modeling/blob/master/src/by_hand_code/prony.py